# Automate commandline application for another user

Tags: shell-script, echo

i have a problem with the following command. I want to write a script that sets the vncpasswd for another user. If I run the following command it will only work for the current user.

```
#< echo "passw0rd\npassw0rd\nn" | vncpasswd
```

But when running the next command, i get a problem because the resulting echo is not a valid input for the programm anymore.

```
#< su nonrootuser -c "echo "passw0rd\npassw0rd\nn" | vncpasswd"

#> Using password file /home/nonrootuser/.vnc/passwd
#> Password: Warning: password truncated to the length of 8.
#> Verify:   Passwords do not match. Please try again.
```

Thanks for your answers! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the shell, the `echo` command may or may not perform backslash expansion to turn `\n` into a newline. For example, bash does not by default, but does after `shopt -s xpg_echo`.

But even if the `echo` builtin of `sh` performs backslash expansion on your machine, your code won't trigger that because of how you wrote the command. You're passing the string `echo passw0rdnpassw0rdnn | vncpasswd` to the `su` command: the second double quote terminates the double-quoted string literal and the third double quote starts a new double-quoted string literal, so the `\n` sequences are not in double quotes in the outer shell and so `\n` expands to `n`. You meant to write something like

```
su nonrootuser -c "echo -e 'passw0rd\npassw0rd\nn' | vncpasswd"
```

so that the backslashes are passed literally through both shells, and with the `-e` option passed to `echo` to tell it to perform backslash expansion.

But rather than fiddle with `echo` in a not entirely portable way, just call `printf` (which is fully reliable) or run `echo` once for each line:

```
su nonrootuser -c "{ echo 'passw0rd'; echo 'passw0rd'; echo n; } | vncpasswd"
```

```
su nonrootuser -c "printf '%s\n' 'passw0rd' 'passw0rd' n | vncpasswd"
```

```
su nonrootuser -c "
  vncpasswd <<EOF
passw0rd
passw0rd
n
EOF"
```